# Terms query(ElasticSearch) not working for some field values

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my Mapping where i have already declared my required field as keywordbut yet my terms query is not working for category_name and storeName but it is working fine for price.

```
 "mappings": {
            "properties" : {
            "firebaseId":{
            "type":"text"
            },
                "name" : {
                   "type" : "text",
                   "analyzer" : "synonym"

                },
                "name_auto" : {
                "type": "text",

    "fields": {
      "edgengram": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
      },
      "completion": {
        "type": "completion"
      }

    }
                },

                "category_name" : {
                            "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": { 
                                    "type": "keyword"
                            }
                }
                },
                "storeName" : {
                      "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": { 
                                    "type": "keyword"
                }
                }
                },
                "sku" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "price" : {
                    "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": { 
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                }
                },
                "magento_id" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "seller_id" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "square_item_id" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "square_variation_id" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "typeId" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```

This is my query below :

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "Category Filter": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_name",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "Store Filter": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "storeName",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "Price Filter": {
      "range": {
        "field": "price",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 50
          },
          {
            "from": 50,
            "to": 100
          },
          {
            "from": 100,
            "to": 200
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which returns as follows :

"reason": {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [category_name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `.keyword` sub-field, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "Category Filter": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_name.keyword",    <-- change this
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "Store Filter": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "storeName.keyword",        <-- change this
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "Price Filter": {
      "range": {
        "field": "price",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 50
          },
          {
            "from": 50,
            "to": 100
          },
          {
            "from": 100,
            "to": 200
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```